# Activate last created book Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro that opens the latest created workbook. I have a macro that formats a spreadsheet followed by splitting those records out and into a new workbook. I want this new workbook I created to be active when the macro finishes.

The salespeople could have numerous workbooks open so I just need something like:

```
Workbooks("Most Recent Workbook").Activate
or
Workbooks(MAX).Activate
```

I know things for most recent worksheet created but that's it.

Comment: When you create a new workbook by Workbooks.Add, it will return a Workbook object. Just store that using a variable and call `Activate` at the end of your macro.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!